Copy a ContentControl from one table cell to another table cell in the same table in Word using VBA
I am trying to copy a ContentControl from a cell in a word table to another cell in the same word table.
I know some Excel VBA, but very little Word VBA.
The code below is supposed to copy the ContentControl that is in Cell 2,4 to Cell 44,4 in the same table.
The code below gives the following error "Run-time error '5941', The requested member of the collection does not exist" on the last line.
Any help would be appreciated.
Sub CopyContentControl()
Dim OCC As ContentControl
Set OCC = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 4).Range.ContentControls(1)
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(44, 4).Range.ContentControls(1) = OCC
End Sub


To replicate the entire cell, you could use:
Sub CopyContentControl()
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  Set Rng = .Cell(2, 4).Range: Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  .Cell(44, 4).Range.FormattedText = Rng.FormattedText
End With
End Sub

If all you want is the content control (e.g. not other cell content), you could use:
Sub CopyContentControl()
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  .Cell(44, 4).Range.FormattedText = .Cell(2, 4).Range.ContentControls(1).Range.FormattedText
End With
End Sub


The first routine works except for two small issues. The content control is showing up in column 3 instead of 4. And there is a small box with a ? in it that is in the first column. It is finding the correct content control in row 2, column 4 though. Does this have to do with my formatting of the text somewhere?

Seems there is a transient bug in Word - it happens sometimes, but not others. Code revised. I have no idea what the small box with a ? in it is about. I'm not seeing that. Did you try the second version of the code?

Code rewrite worked perfectly. Also took care of the ? in the small box. The content control is a drop down list and the second code just copied what is selected in the cell from the drop down list. Not the entire drop down list. Thanks for the help.
